# Is Gazebo planning registering for Google Summer of Code this year?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is gazebo planning registering for [GSOC13](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/homepage/google/gsoc2013) ?

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2041/is-gazebo-planning-registering-for-google-summer-of-code-this-year?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, it is. We are preparing the ideas list for submission. If we are admitted, we'll send all the information to the gazebo mailing list soon.

Stay tuned...

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-03-24**:
awesome :)